# Can a Tile-In sink be installed on top of laminate countertop

Tags: construction, kitchen-sink, countertops

I like the look of Tile-In sinks because of their flush rim.  Can this type of sink be safely installed on a laminate countertop?

Comment: So how do you recess the sink into the top and seal it?

Comment: I don't have expertise in sink installation.  I will eventually hire someone to do it,  but needed to know if it was even possible before I begin searching for a sink.

Comment: I may have given the wrong name (Tile-in) to the sink.  I actually want a cast iron sink that typically uses a metal rim around it, but don't want to use a metal rim.  Can the metal rim be left off, or is this type of sink only designed for metal rims?

Comment: You'll have an unfinished edge where you cut out for the sink. Without the metal rim I can't see how you will seal the gap between the sink and that unfinished edge. I also think that metal rim holds the sink in place. Water is really bad for a laminate countertop when it reaches the unfinished area. Maybe post a photo of the sink you want to use.

Comment: That answers my question, so I will look at alternatives.